# IronPython: Dynamically assign python named parameters from .net's Dictionary

Tags: ironpython, introspection, named-parameters

i want to dynamically assign parameter values coming from a .net's Dictionary instance, 
like this:

```
def Evaluator(IEvaluator):
    def Execute(self, parameters):
        a = parameters['a']
        b = parameters['b']
        c = parameters['c']
        d = parameters['d']
        e = parameters['e']
        return self.Sum(a, b, c, d, e)

    def Sum(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        return a + b + c + d + e
```

I would like to find a way to programatically assign variable values from the dictionary, something
like this:

```
def Evaluator(IEvaluator):
    def Execute(self, parameters):
        return self.Sum(SetParametersByName(parameters))

    def Sum(Self, a, b, c, d, e):
        return a + b + c + d + e
```

I know this may not be possible exactly as i wrote, but you get the idea.

Thank you very much,

Esteban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def Execute(self, parameters):
    return self.Sum(**parameters)
```

If not, you'll have to convert the .NET `Dictionary` to a Python `dict` first (and let me know, so I can file a bug):

```
def Execute(self, parameters):
    return self.Sum(**dict(parameters))
```

This feature is often referred to as 'kwargs', I don't believe it has an official name.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Execute(self, parameters):
    return self.Sum(**parameters)
```

will automatically convert .net Dictionary instance into ** python dictionary

Thank you very much.